# I am looking for a statistical test to test AstraZeneca vaccine thrombosis ADR total vs Astrazeneca thrombosis ADR fatal over date (time)

Tags: t-test

[image]

I'm looking for a test whether the thrombosis total ADR vs thrombosis ADR fatal is statiscally significant and determine if there is a possible trend.

The fatal column is part of thrombosis total as well.

I was looking at a paired t-test as part of the same sample.

Comment: Please clarify what "total ... vs fatal" refers to, because obviously the rates of those two quantities consistently differ by two orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t compute a p-value without having a record of which subjects and in which time slice.  But you can do a useful analysis.  Compute the number of days from 27/01/2021.  Compute the sequential increments in the last 2 columns.  Take the ratio of increment in fatal vs. increment in column 2.  Make a scatterplot of the ratio over time.  Compute Spearman’s $\rho$ correlation between days from 27/01/2021 and the ratio.  Don’t compute a p-value from $\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but this is not a sensible thing to do.

Comparing a total to a subset of that total is not good. If you wanted, you could separate fatal vs. non-fatal and see if those are different, but, they clearly are, you don't really need a test. Still, if you wanted to do this, a paired t-test would not be the way, there is no pairing here. You would want some time series method.

As for trend, yes, of course there is a trend. Since both of these are totals over time, both can only go up or stay stable. So, I would look at deaths or total in each time period. And, since the time periods are not equal (some are 1 week, some are more than 1 month), I would divide by the number of days in each time period. Then you could fit curves to each.

If you are doing this just for yourself (or a class project) then the above should be OK.  If it part of a serious analysis, then I strongly urge you to consult with a professional statistician (not me, I've retired). Time series are tricky.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is part of a class project. Would it be pointless to get a P value? And what do you mean get the number of days in each time period?

Comment: Telling people their scientific objective is "not sensible" doesn't work too well.  It's scarcely for us, as statisticians, to disparage what people might want to know.  I believe what you might have meant to say is that applying textbook procedures (that assume independence) to compare data to a subset is inappropriate.  And your assertion about "no pairing" is difficult to swallow, given there is an obvious pairing of the two data columns based on "data lock date."

Comment: The number of days in each time period is simply the time from one to the next row.  E.g. from Jan 27 to Feb 24 is, I think, 29 days.

As for a p value, well, what's your hypothesis?